# loading values of a text file into an array

Tags: c++, text-files, multidimensional-array, fstream

The text file I generate from an graph generator is similar to:

```
:0 0|-   1|82  2|72
:1 0|87  1|-   2|74
:2 0|86  1|53  2|-
```

These are supposed to represent node and the distance to them.
line 1 is :1 1|- 2|82 3|72
it is saying the distance from node 0 to node 0 (0|-) is - (infinity)

and from node 0 to node 1 (1|82) is 82

and from node 0 to node 2 (2|72) is 72

But I want to load the values into a 2d array.
the array above should be

```
Graph[0][0] = -
Graph[0][1] = 82
Graph[0][2] = 72
etc...
```

I'm just not sure how when I read in the txt file to catch the :0 & :1 & :2 then separate 1|5.

any help would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean separate the `1|5`? Where is that?

Comment: If you think the association between your input file and your representation in that hand-coded array is crystal-clear, let me assure you right now; it *isn't*.

Comment: You can turn your file into a string and index the characters from there. However, I'm still quite fuzzy on how your array and file match.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is those `-` characters. If you replace them with `0`, then you can use something like the following code:

```
// Open the file like this:
// std::ifstream fin ("whatever.txt");

char dummy;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    int x, d;
    fin >> dummy >> x;  // read ":1", etc.
    assert (dummy == '=');
    assert (x == i + 1);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        fin >> x >> dummy >> d;  // read "2|42", etc.
        assert (dummy == '|');
        assert (x == j + 1);
        Graph[i][j] = d;
    }
}
```

All those `assert`s are there to make sure the redundant data in the file are as they are supposed to be. And don't forget to replace all '-'s with '0's.

You can see what I'm doing there. I'm reading the integers normally, and reading a character when the `':'` and `'|'` symbols are.

Comment: '-' stands for 'infinity'. It's tempting to forsake C++ and just use `fgets` and parse "manually". But you'd still need a way to save "infinity" in whatever data type the OP uses; `Graph[0][0] = -` will only work for strings.

Comment: On second thought: the distance from a node to itself *is* 0, not some huge distance... (Maybe it's to discourage infinite backtracking?)

Comment: @Jongware: This is the simplest code that solves OP's problem. I don't think pointer spaghetti/hand parsing/regular expressions are good solutions here. Also, as I mention in my answer, just replacing `-` with `0` makes the parsing quite easier.

Comment: Yes, it's a C++ solution where mine is pure C (... pointer spaghetti? Seriously?). However, you discard the `'-'=INF` and suggest the OP change his data. IMO that is totally unnecessary.

Comment: @Jongware: I'm not saying your code is bad at all. What I'm saying is, given the OP's problem and question, I think any code that uses any pointer manipulation and manual string handling seems way beyond his/her level of C/C++ programming abilities, so I suggested a small change in data (which significantly simplifies the parsing code, and can be achieved using a text editor) and the simplest solution I could think of.

Answer (score 0):

A plain C approach which you may re-write as C++ or just use as-is. After all, this doesn't look like C++ critical code.

Note the use of a *maximum* length for `fgets` (granted, a C++ string could work better here) and a `#define` for "infinity", since you cannot store this value in a sensible way. It assumes all of your distances are positive, and that your data is as you have shown (i.e., no surprises such as *huge* numbers > MAX_INT, or inconsistent spacing).

The usual C++ approach of `cin` does not work well here, and neither does `fscanf`, since in both cases you need to read *one* character, determine if it is an `-` and if it is not re-read itself and any digits following it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 120
#define DIST_INFINITY   0xFFFFFFFF

unsigned int Graph[10][3];

int main (void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char input_string[MAX_DATA_LENGTH], *token_ptr;
    int graph_counter = 0, i;

    fp = fopen ("graph.txt", "rt");
    if (!fp)
    {
        printf ("data not found\n");
        return -1;
    }

    do
    {
        if (fgets (input_string, MAX_DATA_LENGTH, fp) == NULL)
            break;
        token_ptr = input_string;
        for (i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            token_ptr = strchr (token_ptr, '|');
            if (!token_ptr || !token_ptr[1])
                break;
            token_ptr++;
            if (*token_ptr == '-')
                Graph[graph_counter][i] = DIST_INFINITY;
            else
                Graph[graph_counter][i] = strtoul (token_ptr, NULL, 10);
            token_ptr++;
        }
        if (i < 3)
            break;
        graph_counter++;
    } while (1);

    for (i=0; i<graph_counter; i++)
        printf ("Graph[%d] = %u %u %u\n", i, Graph[i][0], Graph[i][1], Graph[i][2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I also assume the `:0` numbers are simply line numbering and the `0|` numbers are indexes. My code happily *ignores* them, but if they mean something (i.e. your data might jump from line `:10` to line `:12` and you need to save that information) it's easily adjusted.